# Change password first Log In sudo su with Cloud-init

Tags: linux, passwords, cloud-init

I'm trying to implement this rule with cloud init but I can't, I would like the user to have a password entered by me but as soon as he executes the sudo su command, the system forces the user to change password. How can I do this via Cloud-Init?
I state that the user connects in SSH and is not prompted for a password.

```
  - name: prova
    groups: sudo
    plain_text_passwd: 1234
    sudo: ['ALL=(ALL) ALL']
    lock_passwd: false
    chpasswd: {expire: True}
    ssh_pwauth: false
```

I tried to do it like this but it doesn't work, can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: This question has been duplicated (and answered) [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/724848/change-password-first-log-in-sudo-su-with-cloud-init).